# Play RTSP/MMS/Http live video feeds in WPF

Tags: wpf, video, video-streaming, live-video

I'd like to pull a live video feed into WPF but the MediaElement doesn't appear to support these protocols.  An example video stream is here (BP oil leak live feed):

http://mfile.akamai.com/97892/live/reflector:45683.asx?bkup=45684

Are there any solutions for playing live streaming formats in WPF?

I had hopes for using the VideoLan DotNet component but it appears to be incompatible with the latest VLC releases:
http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/

Comment: actually the videolan dotnet component works pretty well, you just need to install vlc 2.1 from nightly builds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this isn't currently possible in Windows 7:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150326033001/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/mediasdkstuff/archive/2009/02/05/rendering-a-url-with-graphedit.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking an IP Camera, point the WPF Chrome browser to it:

http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2009/08/27/wpf-3d-chromium-browser/

(you'll need to license the Awesomium wrapper if it's a commercial app).

If it's just webcam stuff, use the WPF MediaKit:

http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/

I've run both in Windows 7.